# C function doesn't work as supposed, `func` doesn't count substring in `str`

Tags: c

i wrote a function mx_substr_count, that counts the substrings "sub" in the string "str"

I cant understand what i`m do wrong.

```
#include "mx_strstr.c"
#include "mx_strchr.c"
#include "mx_strlen.c"
#include "mx_strncmp.c"
#include <stdio.h>

int mx_strncmp(const char *s1, const char *s2, int n);
int mx_strlen(const char *s);
char *mx_strchr(const char *s, int c);
char *mx_strstr(const char *s1, const char *s2);

int mx_count_substr(const char *str, const char *sub);

int main(void)
{
    const char str[] = "yo, yo, yo Neo";
    const char sub[] = "yo";

    mx_count_substr(str, sub);
}

int mx_count_substr(const char *str, const char *sub)
{
    int coincidence;
    const char *temp = str;

    while(temp = mx_strstr(temp, sub))
    {
        coincidence++;
        temp++;
    }

    printf("Coincidence: %i \n", coincidence);
    return coincidence;
}
```

The functions in code that you will see below are standard functions of standard C libraries, but they were written by me manually. They work absolutely as they should. All tests passed.

The actual output in the func below must be 3, but i always have 1.

There is a another functions:

mx_strstr.c:

```
int mx_strncmp(const char *s1, const char *s2, int n);
int mx_strlen(const char *s);
char *mx_strchr(const char *s, int c);

char *mx_strstr(const char*s1, const char*s2);
char *mx_strstr(const char*s1, const char*s2)
{
    int i = 0;

    if(mx_strlen(s1) < mx_strlen(s2))
    {
        return 0;
    }

    while(s1[i] != '\0')
    {
        if(mx_strncmp(s1, s2, mx_strlen(s2)) == 0)
        {
            return mx_strchr(s1, *s2);
        }
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

mx_strncmp.c:

```
int mx_strncmp(const char *s1, const char *s2, int n);

int mx_strncmp(const char *s1, const char *s2, int n)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if(s1[i] != s2[i])
        {
            return (int)(s1[i] - s2[i]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

mx_strlen.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int mx_strlen(const char *s)
{
    int number = 0;    while(s[number] != '\0')
    {        
         number++;
    }
    return number;
}
```

mx_strchr.c:

```
char *mx_strchr(const char *s, int c);
char *mx_strchr(const char *s, int c)
{
    for(int i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        if(s[i] == c)
        {
            return (char *)&s[i];
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: C and C++ are two *very* different languages.

Comment: Please add the source code for mx_strstr and all its subfunctions. It's hard to tell what is wrong with only this snippet

Answer (score 1):

Your `coincidence` variable is **not initialized** and has no determinable value and your code invokes undefined behaviour.

You need to initialize it with `0`;

```
int mx_count_substr(const char *str, const char *sub);

int main(void)
{
    const char str[] = "yo, yo, yo Neo";
    const char sub[] = "yo";

    mx_count_substr(str, sub);
}

int mx_count_substr(const char *str, const char *sub)
{
    int coincidence = 0;
    const char *temp = str;

   /* ... */
```

https://godbolt.org/z/4b6P47Mrh

I would also suggest adding the length of the `sub` string to the `temp` pointer as it does not make any sense to search in that area.

```
int mx_count_substr(const char *str, const char *sub)
{
    int coincidence = 0;
    const char *temp = str;
    size_t subLen = strlen(sub);

    while((temp = strstr(temp, sub)))
    {
        coincidence++;
        temp += subLen;
    }

    printf("Coincidence: %d \n", coincidence);
    return coincidence;
}
```

I am using standard library functions - replace them with your ones.